# How does weekly reminders work?

Tags: javascript, dayofweek, reminders, gettimeofday

Is there an algorithm for weekly reminders ?

For example, I set a reminder for Thursday & I check the "weekly" option.
The Reminder is supposed to alert every Thursday then,but how is this done?

I thought about an idea, but I guess it's very stupid:

1. Get today's "day".
2. Get today's "date".
3. Get the wanted day number.
4. Subtract both days from each other.
5. using [4] get that day's date.
6. Increment the counter after every alert with 7.

I don't even know whether this will work or not, I'm sure there is a better way to do it, so I need your opinions before starting implementation.

PS: I use JavaScript so the functions are very limited.

Comment: Think about your question and what context it needs to be answered. You might have that knowledge, but unless you put it down coherently as a defined question it's very hard to answer specially.

Comment: can you be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish? For example, if you want a function to be called every seven days, you could simply do a `setTimeout(myFunction, 3600*24*7);` at the end of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

1. If your code needs to know whether it's Thursday, that's really easy using [`getDay`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.16), which gives you the day of the week:

   ```
   if (new Date().getDay() === 4) {
       // It's Thursday
   }
   ```

   The [day numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.6) start with `0` = Sunday.
2. If your code needs to find the next Thursday starting on a given date:

   ```
   var dt = /* ...the start date... */;
   while (dt.getDay() !== 4) {
       dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + 86400000)) // 86400000 = 1 day in milliseconds
   }
   ```

   or of course without the loop:

   ```
   var dt = /* ...the start date... */;
   var days = 4 - dt.getDay();
   if (days < 0) {
       days += 7;
   }
   dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + (days * 86400000));
   ```
3. If you have a Thursday already and you need to know the date for the next Thursday:

   ```
   var nextThursday = new Date(thisThursday.getTime() + (86400000 * 7));
   ```